# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command ... is not found

Tags: python, discord.py

My discord bot is able to run its on_message code, but when i try and run a command %ping it errors out and says "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found".

I have imported all the needed modules, wrote client.run(token) at the bottom and defined my token and client object, i didn't deem it necessary to include those lines of code.

I've included await client.process_commands(message) and shifted the code around, i don't know what to do.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    if online:
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Command prefix: " + compref))
    else:
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status("offline"))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #print(message.author)
    #print(client.user)
    if message.author == client.user:
        await client.process_commands(message)
        return
    else:
        #print(message.channel.name)
        try:
            # Create target Directory
            os.mkdir(str(message.author.guild.name))
            #print("Guild msg Directory Created ")
        except FileExistsError:pass
            #print("Guild msg Directory already exists")
        try:
            os.mkdir(str(message.author.guild.name) + "\\message_logs")
        except FileExistsError:pass
            #print("Guild msg Directory already exists")
        with open(str(message.author.guild.name) + "\\message_logs\\" + str(message.channel.name) + "_message_log.json", "a") as c:
            ec = (time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())) + "; " + str(message.author.name) + ": " + message.content).encode("utf-8")
            #print(ec)
            c.write(str(ec))
            c.write("\n")
            c.close()
    await client.process_commands(message)



@client.command
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"pong {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")
    server = ctx.message.author.guild
    server_name = server.name
    server_id = server.id
    server_owner = server.owner.name
    print("")
    print("hi")
    print("server name: {}\n"
          "server id: {}\n"
          "server owner: {}"
          .format(server_name, server_id, server_owner))
    print("")
    try:
        # Create target Directory
        os.mkdir(str(server.name))
        print("Guild Directory ", str(server.name),  " Created ") 
    except FileExistsError:pass
        #print("Guild Directory ", str(server.name),  " already exists")

    with open(str(server.name) + "\\" + str(server.name) + "_info.json", "w") as s:
        e = "Server name: " + server.name + "\n" + "Server ID: " + str(server_id) + "\n" + "Server Owner: " + server_owner
        #print(e)
        s.write(e)
        s.close()

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Bot.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command) is a function that returns a decorator, not a decorator itself.  You need to call it:

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"pong {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")
    server = ctx.message.author.guild
    server_name = server.name
    server_id = server.id
    server_owner = server.owner.name
    print("")
    print("hi")
    print("server name: {}\n"
          "server id: {}\n"
          "server owner: {}"
          .format(server_name, server_id, server_owner))
    print("")
    try:
        # Create target Directory
        os.mkdir(str(server.name))
        print("Guild Directory ", str(server.name),  " Created ") 
    except FileExistsError:pass
        #print("Guild Directory ", str(server.name),  " already exists")

    with open(str(server.name) + "\\" + str(server.name) + "_info.json", "w") as s:
        e = "Server name: " + server.name + "\n" + "Server ID: " + str(server_id) + "\n" + "Server Owner: " + server_owner
        #print(e)
        s.write(e)
        s.close()
    # Remove the process_commands, we're already in a command
```